# Can I see if battery is connected in Windows?

Tags: windows

I was wondering that is there a command that I can see if I'm charging the laptop? And Is there a way to see from a command line the time when one unplugs the charger's wire?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this article](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001232.htm):

If your battery is not shown in the Windows Notification Area (like the example picture to the right), follow the steps below for the version of Windows you're running:

[image]

[Missing battery icon in Windows 8 and Windows 10](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001232.htm#windows-10)

[Missing battery icon in Windows Vista and 7](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001232.htm#windows-7)

[Missing battery icon in Windows XP and 2000](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001232.htm#windows-xp)